# Are Eldritch Knight cantrip choices limited?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, fighter, cantrips

An Eldritch Knight is limited to the schools of Abjuration and Evocation with the exception of certain levels in 5E. Does that limitation carry over to my choice in cantrips?

Answer (score 10):

### No, the restriction only applies to levelled spells.

Cantrips and spells are listed in two separate headings. There is no text connecting the limitation on Spells Known to the ability to cast Cantrips.

> **Cantrips.** You learn two cantrips of your choice from the wizard spell list. You learn an additional wizard cantrip of your choice at 10th level.
>
> **Spells Known of 1st-Level and Higher**
>   You know three 1st-level wizard spells of your choice, two of which you must choose from the abjuration and evocation spells on the wizard spell list.
>
> The Spells Known column of the Eldritch Knight Spellcasting table shows when you learn more wizard spells of 1st level or higher. Each of these spells must be an abjuration or evocation spell of your choice, and must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

Answer (score 4):

## No

> Cantrips. You learn two cantrips of your choice from the wizard spell list. You learn an additional wizard cantrip of your choice at 10th level.

Note that nowhere it says anything about restrictions to the school.

Also note that you start with 1 spell from Any school (and 2 from the Abj/Evo).